# Can’t access Kibana after reload, and enabled & started kibana service. HTTP 302 Error

Tags: kibana-7

I installed elasticSearch (7.4.1) on Ubuntu 18.04.1 server in Virtualbox, and it is working fine. I could create mapping, indexes, and use all the cmds(XPUT, XPOST, XGET ...).

After installing Kibana(7.5.2) in the same server as ES, and updated the Kibana.yml for the following line ONLY:

> server.host: "0.0.0.0"

Kibana server is up and running but it returns HTTP 302. Here are the cmds I used to install and test this issue.

```
sudo apt-get install kibana
sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable kibana.service
sudo /bin/systemctl start kibana.service
```

After waiting for few minutes I checked the kibana log

```
journalctl -u kibana.service
```

Once I could see the kibana is up and running as below

> "tags":["info","http","server","Kibana"],"pid":3388,"message":"http
>   server running at http://0.0.0.0:5601"}

I called the url with `curl` and it returns HTTP 302 Error

```
curl -I localhost:5601

curl -I 127.0.0.1:5601

curl -I 0.0.0.0:5601
```

If I use -IL and it returns HTTP 503 Error

```
curl -IL localhost:5601
```

Here is the kibana log

> "head","statusCode":302,"req":{"url":"/","method":"head","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","user-agent":"curl/7.58.0","
>   ........

How can I fix this 302 error?
I tried to restart the services, Ubuntu server, and reinstall Kibana, same error.

Comment: Did you check if this is the same problem described at https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/10335 ? Somebody fixed by changing kibana password, other cleaning cookies. other atching kibana (see last comment from c4milo).

Comment: I installed and config elasticSearch and kibana in a virtualbox as sandbox env. I didn't change the pw. I did try uncomment the following 2 lines in the yml file, and restarted the service. Same problem.

elasticsearch.username: "kibana"
elasticsearch.password: "pass"